# Book about semimartingales and stochastic integral w.r.t semimartingales

Tags: stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation

Is there an English version of Dellacherie C and Meyer P ,,probabilites et potentiel''? Or what books on semimartingals and stochastic calculus do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

There is an English version, it can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/072040701X) .

Comment: Thanks, do you know some other book about semimartingales and stochastic integration with respect to semimartingales?

Comment: No, I am sorry I am not into this, I just know the book from a friend.